# why does python requests.post accept json for data but not a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-requests

The documentation seems to indicate I can pass 'data=' as a dictionary, but I get an error unless I use `json.dumps()`

```
options = {
    "deviceId":["4d51de64-2235-a465-3aee-5ec495b5b250"],
    "serviceName":"software_manager",
    "serviceVersion":"1.0",
    "actionName":"Dump Log Files" }

res = requests.post( req, data=json.dumps(options), auth=cred)
```

If I try to pass options as a dictionary it fails.

```
res = requests.post( req, data=options, auth=cred) 

data=json.dumps(options) # This works
data=options             # this fails
```

Why? Am I missing something in the docs?

Comment: Fails *how*? Show the error.

Comment: You should use `res = requests.post( req, json=options, auth=cred)`.

Comment: You need to check what kind of media is the destination is expecting with POST. It might be failing cause the destination only accepts json.

Comment: Thanks! json= works, data= does not.

Comment: The error was simply status_code = 400

Answer (score 3):

The `data` parameter of [`requests.post()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) either accepts data as form-encoded (if you pass it a `dict`) or as a raw string (which is why `json.dumps(options)` works).

In order to pass in a non-encoded dictionary, you should use the `json` parameter of `.post()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed the part about "form-encoded" ... http newbie!